# How are the CPU-modes applied? (x86)

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, x86

The normal operating mode of the CPU is the [Protected Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode).

It still starts in Real-mode for backwards compatibility reasons.

> Real mode, also called real address mode, is an operating mode of all x86-compatible CPUs. Real mode is characterized by a 20-bit segmented memory address space (giving exactly 1 MiB of addressable memory) and unlimited direct software access to all addressable memory, I/O addresses and peripheral hardware.

With the introduction of the amd64/x86_64 ISA extension, long mode was introduced, common 64bit registers were added and only in long mode software can be executed on them.

My question is: on a multicore CPU, can the different cores be in different CPU-modes? Is it the casual way of how the thing/how execution works? Or is it completely impossible?

Also does this behaviour apply to all ISA? What about a multicore ARM?  (Which has a lot more then just 2 casual modes)

Comment: No; They cannot be in different modes.  No; It only applies to x86;  Different architectures have different rules

Comment: add some explanation, post it as an answer and I accept and upvote it.
Also I would be very thankful because I couldn't find a source were this is explained.